# ORDER BY percentage in mysql - 100% is moved to the end

Tags: mysql, sql, select

here's my query to arrange the percentage in a correct descenting order.

```
SELECT
id, 
concat(round(100 * ( count(t5.answ IN (t1.answ, t2.answ, t3.answ)) ) / case when t6.name < 4 then 100 when t6.name = 4 then 200 when t6.name > 4 then 300 end,0)) as score,
another_column
from t1
order by score desc
```

the `score` output is

```
91%, 96%, 100%, 92%,
```

What iam looking for this

```
100%, 96%, 92%, 91%
```

but what i get is this, the 100% is moved to the end

```
order by score desc
// 96%, 92%, 91%, 100%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are ordering by a string and not a number.  Given the complexity of the expression, just convert back to a number for ordering:

```
order by (score + 0) desc
```

Comment: I get an error `Reference 'score' not supported (reference to group function)`

Comment: this works for me `order by 
(concat(round(100 * ( count(t5.answ IN (t1.answ, t2.answ, t3.answ)) ) / case when t6.name < 4 then 100 when t6.name = 4 then 200 when t6.name > 4 then 300 end,0))) + 0) desc`

Comment: I'd use [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast): ``ORDER BY CAST(`score` AS SIGNED) DESC`` which more is more explicit about what you're doing (as opposed to `+ 0` that could be misunderstood to be a typo and accidentally removed).

Comment: @0b10011 . . . There must've been a time when MySQL generated an error in that case, because I distinctly remember switching to implicit conversion to avoid the error.